# regex match words and combinations of words without trailing space

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out regex pattern for situation like this in order to serialize results:

```
"july 25, 2010" => ([0]=>july)

"red, white, blue" => ([0]=>red, [1]=>white, [2]=>blue)

"redish blue, orange" => ([0]=>redish blue, [1]=>orange)

"july 2015" => ([0]=>july)

"that's awesome" => ([0]=>that's awesome)
```

I want to capture all words/word combinations with limitations:

- only words not numbers or characters except apostrophe
- words with a space in between to be included together

So far I've come up with:

```
\w[A-Za-z ']+
```

but I get trailing spaces. So this matches "july " and not "july". How can I prevent trailing spaces while maintaining spaces in between words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a single last character match without the space:
`\w[A-Za-z ']*[A-Za-z']`

See [sample](https://regex101.com/r/tC4zJ4/2)

Comment: However yours much more simple, fast.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way would be:

```
[a-z][a-z' ]*(?= |,|$)
```

That's using a [lookahead zero-length assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), conditionally matching either a space, a comma or the end of the string. Also, it will match words of any length, like "I" or "hi".

See it in [action](https://regex101.com/r/rA9zC1/3).